# Delete file from server

Tags: c#, sql, file-upload, delete-file

I have an application that I am using as a file uploader with an admin panel on the backend of things. I have most of everything completed on it, but I'm running into a wall where I can't delete the physical file from the server. Permissions are correct to allow such action.

On the click of a delete button next to the entry I'm calling the primary ID of the row and as such I'm able to call from the SQL the stored filePath. Here's my code to do so:

```
DbConn dbConnx = new DbConn();
   SQL = "SELECT filePath FROM database WHERE id='"+ primaryID +"'";
   myReader = dbConnx.createDataReader(SQL);
string fn44 = Convert.ToString(myReader.Read());
string url = fn44; //I know redundant
System.IO.File.Delete(url);
```

All I'm able to gather is that the only information that is pulled is 'true'. I believe this is because I'm trying to convert the information to a string and it doesn't like that. How would I go about taking the value stored in SQL and using it with a variable to perform the delete?

Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give us an example "url" or path you are getting from the database.

Comment: **WARNING**:  Your code has a [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) vulnerability.

Comment: I've never seen the delete method take a URL. I always thought you needed a drive letter or a UNC path. (C:\\ or \\server\share)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the primaryID is actually not set by the user it's set when the user clicks on the delete button. I'm using command arguments and datakeys to set the value of it. I can easily change it though so thanks for pointing out the risk!

Comment: And the url is actually looking for the server path. I just incorrectly refer to it as URL in my code, It's been a long day. It does use the C:\\reference to the data folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the datatype of myReader, but assuming that is a DataReader of some kind then calling

```
myReader.Read();
```

returns a boolean value that tells you if the datareader is positioned on a valid row or not.

To get the content of the record on which the reader is positioned (assuming the previous call returns true) you need to write

```
 myReader = dbConnx.createDataReader(SQL);
 if(myReader.Read())
 {
     string fn44 = Convert.ToString(myReader[0]);
      ....
 }
```

Your code has another problem called Sql Injection.
You should not use string concatenation with user input when building a sql command. 
You use a parameterized query like this

```
 SQL = "SELECT filePath FROM database WHERE id=@p1";
 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(......))
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
 {
     con.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",primaryID); 
     using(SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
        .....
     }
 }
```

yyy

Having fixed the reading from the database, now you need to check what kind of string is stored in the FilePath field in the database. Remember that every file IO operation on a web site should get to the effective file name using the [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method

Comment: Thanks for this info. C#/asp.net is not my strongest language. This is pretty easy to handle in PHP but a bit more complicated here. myReader is a SqlDataReader I created to store the data. I didn't realize that .Read() returned boolean, I'll have to keep that in mind for future projects. Thanks for the tip about SQL Injection. The user doesn't have access to specify what the primaryID value is, it's actually the data key that I have assigned to each row. When the delete button is clicked the primaryID variable is created so that I can call up a specific entry in the database.

Comment: For my delete function I have things set up as above. I'll have to do more research to get educated about SQL injection. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Another thing is the `primaryID` variable. You pass it into the sql command between single quotes. This means a string is passed to the database and if the database field is not a string you could get wrong results or even errors.

Comment: Thanks again, I got things working - minus the parameterized query - that's for tomorrow. Went ahead and accepted your answer.